# Cosmos Table API with Concurrency If-Match options for ETag

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using CosmosDB table APIs with `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` and the `CloudTable` object does not offer any update/insert operation which honors the If-Match header on ETag. The available options are below - none of which offer If-Match condtition:

```cs
public static TableOperation Insert(ITableEntity entity);
public static TableOperation Insert(ITableEntity entity, bool echoContent);
public static TableOperation InsertOrMerge(ITableEntity entity);
public static TableOperation InsertOrReplace(ITableEntity entity);
public static TableOperation Merge(ITableEntity entity);
public static TableOperation Replace(ITableEntity entity);
```

How to achieve the If-Match constraint here on update?

PS: Trying to avoid writing a [JS resolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/how-to-manage-conflicts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to achieve the If-Match constraint here on update?

[`ITableEntity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.itableentity?view=azure-dotnet) has a property called [`ETag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.itableentity.etag?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Table_ITableEntity_ETag). For conditional updates, you will need to use that. If you specify `*` for ETag value, the entity will always be updated. If you specify any value other than `*`, an entity will only be updated if the ETag value of the entity on the server matches with the value you have specified.

**UPDATE**

So I wrote some sample code to test conditional update:

```cs
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
var tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
var table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Test");

var entity = new MyEntity();
entity.PartitionKey = "pk4";
entity.RowKey = "rk4";
entity.MyIgnoredProperty = "ignored - updated";
entity.MyOtherProperty = "not ignored - updated";
entity.ETag = "W/\"0x5B168C7B6E589D2\"";//This is a dummy Etag value to fail the replace operation
TableOperation replaceOperation = TableOperation.Replace(entity);
var result = table.Execute(replaceOperation);//Fails with 412 status code
Console.WriteLine(entity.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

and traced the request through Fiddler. If you notice, the `ETag` value is passed as `If-Match` request header.

[image]

Comment: The above operations ignore the ETag and write anyway with older ETag - tried out and observed the same. Am I missing something? Same mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-or-merge-entity#remarks)

Comment: This is because you're doing `Insert or Merge` operation which does not offer conditional updates. You will need to use either `Merge` or `Update` operation if you want to enforce this conditional update. Please see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/update-entity2#remarks.

Comment: Right, thanks. So there will be 2 calls needed - first Insert and if it exists then Merge. Update would have been better as it inserts when entity does not exists. But there is no update method in the TableOperation class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.tableoperation?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: `Replace` operation in SDK maps to `Update Entity` operation in REST API.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But coming back to the previous question - it does not do an insert when the Row Key is not present - even when I pass ETag as "*". Were you able to achieve it?

Comment: Do let me know if you could find a way to Have the entity inserted if it does not exist as part of the Replace call (What Update does).

Comment: For `Replace`, entity has to be present in the table. `Insert` will fail if the entity is present. If you are not sure whether the entity is present or not, you will need to use either `Insert or Replace` or `Insert or Merge` operation.

Comment: Right - missed that InsertOrReplace is an explicit option here.

Comment: But unfortunately it too ignores ETag - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-or-replace-entity#remarks   Looks like 2 call will be needed (Given I don't have info about any state of presence in the client side)